# A blog or newsfeed for innumeracy in the media?

Tags: examples

There are a lot of good particular examples of innumeracy at [this question](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1572/examples-of-innumeracy).  But in addition what I would like is to be able to consistently bring *current* examples in to class.  Does anyone maintain a blog that collects such examples as they occur?

Comment: Mike, I love this question. I read and participated in the linked question. I know there are sites that fact check media and point out their errors. Hopefully we find a few that focus on the math errors.

Comment: One place you might find this is on math blogs that have a relevant tag. Quickly googling led me to the *math-mistakes* tag [**here**](https://threesixty360.wordpress.com/category/math-mistakes/); perhaps it has some good stuff. It is not often updated, but there's at least a nice example in [**this ad**](https://threesixty360.files.wordpress.com/2011/08/yckth.jpg) (captioned by the blog as: *Perhaps the second bar is twice as delicious as the first*).

Comment: If no one finds a good link ... would someone be willing to maintain such a site? Or at least moderate submissions? Hmm maybe I'll do it ...

Comment: @brendansullivan07 I've added a chat room to discuss this. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34405/innumeracy

Answer (score 2):

This one looks promising: http://goodstatsbadstats.com/ But the last posting was in October.